# Calculate price for different hours

Tags: javascript, calculation

I want to calculate the price for parking hours.
The person picks a start time and a end time, and then it should tell you how much it costs. But the hours have different prices.

The prices for parking:

Between 08-18 price: $20 per. hour

Between 18-08 price: $15 per. hour

I guess it would be something kinda this

```
 var start = prompt ('When did your parking start?');
 var end = prompt ('When did your parking end?');

 var price1 = 20
 var price2 = 15

 var time = end - start;
 var price = 20 * time;

 document.getElementById('pris').innerHTML =  price;
```

So how do i calculate the price with different prices for the specific time periods?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do i calculate the price with different prices for specific time periods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does probably not work for edge cases and only for full hours so far but maybe it helps you to understand how it can be done:

```js
const start = prompt("When did your parking start?");
const end = prompt("When did your parking end?");

const price1 = 20;
const price2 = 15;

// hour 0 == hour 24
const prices = [
  { hour: 0, price: price2 },
  { hour: 1, price: price2 },
  { hour: 2, price: price2 },
  { hour: 3, price: price2 },
  { hour: 4, price: price2 },
  { hour: 5, price: price2 },
  { hour: 6, price: price2 },
  { hour: 7, price: price2 },
  { hour: 8, price: price1 },
  { hour: 9, price: price1 },
  { hour: 10, price: price1 },
  { hour: 11, price: price1 },
  { hour: 12, price: price1 },
  { hour: 13, price: price1 },
  { hour: 14, price: price1 },
  { hour: 15, price: price1 },
  { hour: 16, price: price1 },
  { hour: 17, price: price1 },
  { hour: 18, price: price2 },
  { hour: 19, price: price2 },
  { hour: 20, price: price2 },
  { hour: 21, price: price2 },
  { hour: 22, price: price2 },
  { hour: 23, price: price2 },
  { hour: 24, price: price2 }
];

const time = end - start;

let price = 0;
for (let i = 0; i <= time; i++) {
  price += prices[i].price;
}

document.querySelector("#price").innerHTML = price + "$";
```

```html
<h1 id="price"></h1>
```